# Jenkins running C# nunit test in msbuild and not getting correct error code

Tags: c#, powershell, msbuild, nunit

I am running a C# nunit test via Jenkins, the 'build' is successful, but the nunit test fails, when I check LASTEXITCODE I get 0 (success), is there a way of getting the actual result that nunit has.

The output is:

```
Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
   CLR Version: 4.0.30319.34209 ( Net 4.5 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: v4.0
Run list: C:\Jenkins\workspace\regressionTests\TestList.txt

Tests run: 1, Errors: 1, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 45.106507 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0

Errors and Failures:
1) TearDown Error :   
USERACCOUNT = TESTUSER, DEFAULT_CLIENT = UNKNOWN, DEFAULT_ACCOUNT = UNKNOWN)
 Activating Dataflow Dialog
Expected: True within 1000 millisecond delay
But was:  False

TearDown : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any suggestions would be welcome, I tried searching StackOverflow and Google, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you post the script?

Comment: @rrirower I am using Powershell format of & "MSBuild" "$CSPROJ"

Comment: Should be ok if you use plain MSBuild "$CSPROJ" since that should emit the proper error code (I guess: 1)